# QDateEdit object has not attribute "setText"

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5

I want to create a calendar and when I press a date from that calendar, it gets copied to some fields. Currently I am trying to populate only one field and I get an error "QDateEdit object has not attribute "setText"
Code:

```
class Ui_DE(object):


def setupUi(self, DE):
    DE.setObjectName("DE")
    DE.resize(1149, 517)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    DE.setFont(font)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(DE)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.calButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DE)
    self.calButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('calendar.png'))
    self.calButton.setStyleSheet('border: 0px; padding: 0px;')
    self.calButton.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
    self.calButton.clicked.connect(self.showCalWid)
    self.calButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 50, 256, 183))
    self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DE)
    self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 91, 21))
    self.btnStart.setObjectName("Start")
    self.GermanyBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DE)
    self.GermanyBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 60, 91, 21))
    self.GermanyBrowse.setObjectName("GermanyBrowse")
    self.GermanyBrowse.clicked.connect(self.getfile_germany)
    self.GermanyLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(DE)
    self.GermanyLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 71, 21))
    self.GermanyLabel.setObjectName("GermanyLabel")
    self.GermanyDate = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(DE)
    self.GermanyDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 60, 110, 22))
    self.GermanyDate.setObjectName("GermanyDate")
    self.retranslateUi(DE)

  def showCalWid(self):
    self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget()
    self.calendar.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate(1900, 1, 1))
    self.calendar.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(3000, 1, 1))
    self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
    self.calendar.clicked.connect(self.updateDate)
    self.calendar.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.calendar.setStyleSheet('background: white; color: black')
    self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
    pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
    self.calendar.setGeometry(pos.x(), pos.y(), 300, 200)
    self.calendar.show()

  def updateDate(self,*args):
    getDate = self.calendar.selectedDate().toString()
    self.GermanyDate.setText(getDate)
    self.calendar.deleteLater()

  def retranslateUi(self, DE):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    DE.setWindowTitle(_translate("DE", "Dialog"))
    self.GermanyBrowse.setText(_translate("DE", "Browse"))
```

And I am trying to copy the date selected from the calendar to self.GermanyDate

Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a QDate, not a string:

```
self.GermanyDate.setDate(self.calendar.selectedDate())
```